# HTTP module or isapi module on classic asp page to record page hits

Tags: asp-classic

I have a classic ASP app and I'm trying to log each hit on a particular page. I was going to make an include file that wrote to the database, but I wondered if it wouldn't be faster to put something in the HTTP pipeline to do it instead.

Thoughts?

Comment: have you solve this problem. if yes what solutions did you found out

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the page counter component

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020203208/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/032101-1.shtml